# Xamarin Binding: unable to parse Xcode project: Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, objective-sharpie

I'm binding a Objective-C [SDK](https://github.com/qiniu/objc-sdk) use `sharpie pod bind`, got error message:

`System.AggregateException: unable to parse Xcode project: Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

The message detail:

> ---> `System.ObjectDisposedException`: Cannot access a disposed object.
>
> Object name: 'Stream has been closed'.
>   at `System.IO.FileStream.get_Length ()` in :line 0
>   at Xamarin.MacDev.PropertyListFormat+BinaryFormat.StartReading (System.IO.Stream input) in :line 0
>   at Xamarin.MacDev.PropertyListFormat.CreateReadContext (System.IO.Stream input) in :line 0
>   at Xamarin.MacDev.PObject.FromStream (System.IO.Stream stream) in :line 0
>   at Sharpie.Xcode.Project.PBXProjectFile..ctor (System.IO.Stream plistStream) in :line 0
>   at Sharpie.Xcode.Project.PBXProjectFile..ctor (FilePath fileName) in :line 0
>   at Sharpie.Xcode.Project.XcodeProject..ctor (FilePath fileName) in :line 0
>         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Sharpie.Xcode.Project.XcodeProject..ctor (FilePath fileName) in :line 0
>          at Sharpie.ParseTool.LoadXcodeProjectOptions (FilePath xcodeprojFile) in :line 0
>          at Sharpie.ParseTool.Run () in :line 0
>          at Sharpie.BindTool.CoreRun () in :line 0
>          at Sharpie.BindTool.Run () in :line 0
>       ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>       Object name: 'Stream has been closed'.
>          at System.IO.FileStream.get_Length () in :line 0
>          at Xamarin.MacDev.PropertyListFormat+BinaryFormat.StartReading   (System.IO.Stream input) in :line 0
>          at Xamarin.MacDev.PropertyListFormat.CreateReadContext (System.IO.Stream input) in :line 0
>          at Xamarin.MacDev.PObject.FromStream (System.IO.Stream stream) in :line 0
>          at Sharpie.Xcode.Project.PBXProjectFile..ctor (System.IO.Stream plistStream) in :line 0
>          at Sharpie.Xcode.Project.PBXProjectFile..ctor (FilePath fileName) in :line 0
>          at Sharpie.Xcode.Project.XcodeProject..ctor (FilePath fileName) in :line 0 <---
>
> Submitting usage data to Xamarin...
>         Failed to submit. Telemetry will be submitted next time.
>         Error: Insights.PurgeAllPendingData timed out (15s wait)
>
> Done. Exiting with error code 1.

Thanks.

Do I have any other way to bind a `cocoapods` project?

Comment: I'd file a bug: bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: @Jason Thank you, do you know how to bind this sdk manually? I'm badly in need of this sdk. Can you give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

When you create project from cocoa pods links then its headers file were not bind with targets.you have to bind it your self.To Add headers go to follow following paths for this.
(select Pods target > Build Phases > '+'> New Headers phase). 
Now the sharpie pod bind command works fine.

Comment: Still get error: Pods/Pods.xcodeproj does not have a 'Pods' target

Comment: Works for me! Thx.

Comment: Works for me too ! :)